# Cycle2 carousel plugin not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle2

I've been trying to implement the carousel plugin from   cycle2  but  it just doesn't seem to work. even though  its an extremely easy code i just  don't understand what  my problem is.
I've used the regular cycle2 plugin using the  `cycle-slideshow` class  and this works just fine, I don't  know if  it has  anything to do  with  this  file  being a  php file and  its being  included into  other pages,  allthough i don't think so.

```
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href='/plst_main_f/STYLES/extra_styles.css' >
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/plst_main_f/JAVASCRIPT_JQUERY/cycle2.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="/plst_main_f/JAVASCRIPT_JQUERY/carousel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
 <div class="slideshow" 
                        data-cycle-fx=carousel
                        data-cycle-timeout=0
                        data-cycle-carousel-visible=2 >

         <img src='/plst_main_f/IMAGES/favicon_b_w.ico'/>
           //  here  goes about 12 images....  just not adding them so its clearer.     

</div>                   
</body>
```